# Flask form data passed to database and redirect to homepage

Tags: python, flask

OK, so i've been trying to get a form to pass data through to a text file in Flask but every time I do, I get one of these error messages: 
"***Method Not Allowed. The method is not allowed for the requested URL.***"
or 
***Not Found. The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.***

What I'd like to happen is when the user hits submit, be redirected to the homepage with a "Hi username" message. I've tried putting in the form action "/, index, index.html, {{ url_for('index') }}" (this last one just as a long shot but was running out of ideas!)

My Flask code is as follows:

```
@app.route('/signUp', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def signUp():
if request.method == "POST":
    with open("data/users.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(request.form["user"])
else:
    return render_template("signUp.html")
```

My form code is as follows:

```
<form id="loginBox" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="index.html">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="user" class="col-md-2 control-label">Username</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" placeholder="user">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!-- Button -->                                        
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-9">
                            <input type="submit" value="Sign Me Up" class="btn btn-info btn">
                        </div>
                    </div>    
            </form>
```

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're posting to the wrong route, try changing this:

```
<form id="loginBox" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="index.html">
```

into this:

```
<form id="loginBox" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{url_for('signUp')}}">
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. That got it working along with another tweak that I'd missed!